# W3TC Page Cache Url Rewriting is not Working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching, w3-total-cache

I am having trouble getting W3tC page cache to work. I checked the rewrite rules and they are all set on my vps server. I recently set up the vps server through Digital Ocean.

The error I am getting is:

> W3 Total Cache error: It appears Page Cache URL rewriting is not working. Please verify that the server configuration allows .htaccess
>   Unfortunately disk enhanced page caching will not function without custom rewrite rules. Please ask your server administrator for assistance. Also refer to the install page for the rules for your server.

The technical info is 
.htaccess file contains rules to rewrite the URL.
The plugin made a request to `https://example.com/w3tc_rewrite_test` but received: 
404 Not Found instead of "OK" response.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Do any directives work? We'll need to see what directives you have and where they are used. You mention "VPS server" in the question, so I assume these directives are in your server config? However, you have tagged your question `.htaccess`?

Comment: The error disappeared. The fix was to put the wordpress core rewrite rules after the w3tc ones. Caching still does not seem to work however

Comment: If you are still having a problem with caching then maybe the [WordPress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Test with those code in your root/.htaccess

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache  
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary  
   </IfModule>
     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json  
   <IfModule mod_mime.c>
     # DEFLATE by extension  
     AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml  
   </IfModule>  
 </IfModule>
 # END W3TC Browser Cache  
 # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core  
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On  
   RewriteBase /  
   RewriteRule ^(.*/)?w3tc_rewrite_test/?$ $1?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 [L]  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip  
   RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]  
   RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]  
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST  
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""  
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]  
   RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f  
   RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]  
 </IfModule>  
 # END W3TC Page Cache core  
 # BEGIN WordPress  
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On  
         RewriteBase /  
         RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]  
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
         RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
     </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a short answer to @h2kyaw one. If you add the following line in .htaccess **root** directory will enough.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?w3tc_rewrite_test([0-9]+)/?$ $1?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the sequence of the rules that appear in “.htaccess“, make sure WordPress’s rule appears AFTER the W3TC rules.

```
#...
# END W3TC Page Cache core
```

So

The final .htaccess file structure should be like

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
 
......
 
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN WordPress
.....

# END WordPress
```

This is a tested method and worked well. Thank you.

Source: [Fix – W3 Total Cache error: It appears Page Cache URL rewriting is not working – Easy Method](https://www.codehref.com/fix-w3-total-cache-error-it-appears-page-cache/)